# How can I splat/unpack/apply an array of arguments into a function?

Tags: excel, apply, splat

If I have an Excel Array `{2023;3;16}` how can I apply that to a function like `DATE`?

In python I'd splat using `*`: `DATE(*TEXTSPLIT(A1,"."))`

In Excel, do I have to manually unpack it with `TAKE` or `INDEX`?

For example: `=LET(a, {2023;3;16}, DATE(INDEX(a,1), INDEX(a,2), INDEX(a,3))`

Answer (score 0):

Join and then coerce to a (numeric) date:

`=LET(a,{2023;3;16},0+TEXTJOIN("/",,a))`